# Вывести сообщение после редиректа с определенной страницы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте! Может этот вопрос не очень понятный, но у меня есть задача: после регистрации пользователя перенаправляет на страницу confirm.php. Вот её код если пригодится:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$gender = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gender']);
$password = htmlspecialchars(hash("sha512", $_POST['password']));
include "../media/parts/dataBaseConnect.php";
unset($_POST['fruit']);
unset($_POST['register']);
function createRandomStringValidationCode($randomstring){
 $randomstring = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 30);
 return($randomstring);
}

$randomCode = createRandomStringValidationCode($randomCode);

if(isset($_POST['emailCheck'])){
 $checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$_POST[emailCheck]'";
 $resultQuery = mysqli_query($dataBase, $checkQuery);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($resultQuery) > 0){
  echo 'Email has been already used by someone else.';
 }
 else {
  echo 'Email is avalable.';
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['nameCheck'])){
 $checkQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$_POST[nameCheck]'";
 $resultQuery2 = mysqli_query($dataBase, $checkQuery2);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($resultQuery2) > 0){
  echo 'This name is not avalable.';
 }
 else {
  echo 'This name is avalable.';
 }
}

if(empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['password']) or empty($_POST['gender']) or empty($_POST['name'])){
 header("Location: register");
}

$_SESSION['user'] = array(
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => $name,
    'password' => $password,
    'gender' => $gender,
 'validation' => $randomCode,
 'type' => 'register'
);
$to; $subject; $message; $headers; $from;
function sendMail(){
 $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset: UTF-8"."\r\n";
 $to = $_SESSION['user']['email'];
 $from = "rayeugen@gmail.com". "\r\n";
 $subject = "Thanks for youre registration on Eugen Ray\"s Website";
 $message = "Thanks for your registration"." ".$_SESSION['user']['name']." "."\nTo continue usage of Eugen Ray\"s Website, you'll have toe enter code given below on validation page.\nHere's your validation code:"." ".$_SESSION['user']['validation']."\nWish you all the best.\nEugen Ray";
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $from, $headers);
}
sendMail();


header("Location: validate");
?>
```

Так вот в нем есть условие

`if(empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['password']) or empty($_POST['gender']) or empty($_POST['name'])){
    header("Location: register");
}`

Так вот мне надо AJAX запросом на странице register вывести в одно из полей (допустим `<p id="returned"></p>`) вывести сообщение "One of required fields was empty. Try to register one more time". Как это реализовать? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: дак зачем вы делаете редирект? отдайте обратно JSON с ошибками. Если успешно все, то отдайте ссылку для редиректа, и сделайте редирект на стороне клиента.

Comment: Просто у меня в конце редирект на страницу подтверждения кода регистрации. А если пользователь наберет в строке поиска confirm.php он попадет на страницу подтверждения кода даже если он не ввел никаких данных на странице регистрации.

Comment: @teran У меня длина имени проверяется на стороне клиента на странице register.php

Comment: сохраняйте в сессии флаг, что все ОК, и проверяйте в `confirm`

Comment: Использовать redirect с get параметром?

Comment: Реально не вижу необходимости AJAX. Просто после нужного иф-а добавляйте в HTML `<script>` с нужным сообщением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как посоветовал @ilyaplot cделайте проверки через сессии

```
if(empty($_POST['email']) or empty($_POST['password']) or empty($_POST['gender']) or empty($_POST['name'])){
$_SESSION['register_error']=true;
header("Location: register");
}
```

a в файле регистрации в нужном месте вставьте

```
if (isset($_SESSION['register_error']) && ($_SESSION['register_error']==true)) {
echo '<p id="returned">One of required fields was empty. Try to register one more time.</p>';
}
```